# select specific elements in parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to get an article from a div, and the problem is it gets everything when i use `$('#article').html()` is there a way for just getting a spesific html inside the parent div without other elements?

```
<div id="article">
This is an article
blabla
<br/>
<b>something bold here</b>
    <div id="unknown">{some javscript}</div>
    <link type="anything" url="somewhere">
    <style>
        .something
    </style>
the end of the article
</div>
```

should return

```
this is an article
blabla
<br/>
<b>something bold here</b>
the end of the article
```

Comment: You want the `<br/>` and `<b>` tags also?

Comment: yeah, we can filter them later by using `.text()` i guess.

Comment: No, because you're being completely inconsistent with what you want. Nothing in other elements, and yet still keep everything in the `<b>`? Be more specific... honestly.

Comment: you want the div , and stop at next <div>  ?

Comment: so there may be <b> and <br /> embedded in article , but not another <div>  ??

Comment: I am also a little confused on what you want -- are <b> tags and <br /> tags the only exceptions or will there possibly be other exceptions?

Comment: there will be more exceptions, but its just an example for geting an article text not another text, assuming that the article text is inside the parent div. sorry everyone for the inconsistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/TULKC/

```
var el=document.getElementById('article'),
    text=getText(el);
function getText(el){
    var els=el.childNodes,
        t='';
    for(var i=0;i<els.length;i++){
        if(els[i].nodeType==3){//If it's a text node
            if(!/^\s+$/.test(els[i].nodeValue)){//We avoid spaces
                t+=els[i].nodeValue;
            }
        }else if(els[i].nodeType==1){//If it's an element node
            var nName=els[i].nodeName.toLowerCase(),
                c=check(nName);
            if(c==1){//Allowed elements
                t+='<'+nName+'>'+getText(els[i])+'</'+nName+'>';
            }else if(c==2){//Allowed self-closing elements
                t+='<'+nName+' />';
            }
        }
    }
    return t;
}
function check(nodeName){
    switch(nodeName){
        case 'b': return 1;//Allowed elements
        case 'br':return 2;//Allowed self-closing elements
        default:return 0;
    }
}
alert(text);
```

**Note:** You can add more exceptions this way:

```
switch(nodeName){
    case 'b': case 'a':  return 1;//Allowed elements
    case 'br':case 'img':return 2;//Allowed self-closing elements
    default:return 0;
}
```

(Well, if you use HTML5, `img` is not a self-closing element)

**Edit:**

If you want to keep the attributes, you can use the following function

```
function getAttr(el){
    var attr=el.attributes,
        t='';
    for(var i=0;i<attr.length;i++){
        t+=' '+attr[i].nodeName+'="'+attr[i].nodeValue+'"';
    }
    return t;
}
```

and then

```
if(c==1){
    t+='<'+nName+getAttr(els[i])+'>'+getText(els[i])+'</'+nName+'>';
}else if(c==2){
    t+='<'+nName+getAttr(els[i])+' />';
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/TULKC/4/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you what you want I guess:

```
​(function($) {
    $article = $('#article').clone();

    $('div, link, style', $article).remove();

    console.log($article.html());
})(jQuery);​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EQ7zC/

Answer (score 1):

You can use innerText or .text() in jQuery to get all text without tags, including the text in childs.

Also, if you need to get only the text in parent div, without the text of child elements, you can iterate it's child nodes, and check if it is text node.

Something like this:

```
var innerText = "";
$('#yourDiv').each(function(){
var $cn = this.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0, l = $cn && $cn.length || 0; i < l; i++) {
        if ($cn[i].nodeType == 3 && String($cn[i].nodeValue).split(/\s/).join('')) {
            innerText += $cn[i].nodeValue;
        }
    }
});
console.log(innerText);
```

Comment: Why are you looping through an element with an `id`?

Comment: yes, you are right, there are better ways organize the loop. It was just an example, illustrating the principle described above (harmful habit to use for() everywhere).

Comment: I meant more like there can be only one element selected because it is an id, so you don't need a loop at all.

Comment: Yes, but he can try to find that div also by classname or by other selectors - it is jQuery, so in this case we will grab all text correctly.

Answer (score 0):

is this a possibility ?

```
 <div id="article">
   <a>This is an article               -- a starts article 
         blabla
       <br/>
       <b>something bold here</b>
   </a>                                 -- /a ends article

<div id="unknown">{some javscript}</div>
<link type="anything" url="somewhere">
<style>
    .something
</style>
```

the end of the article

```
                   $('#article').find('a').html();
```