# css or jquery selector exclude child

Tags: jquery, css

How do I select the title but not the subtitle here:

```
<h1 id="banner">
This is the Title 
<span id="subtitle">and the subtitle</span>
</h1>
```

I'd like to do something like

```
h1 < span#subtitle {font-weight:bold}
```

or

```
h1:not(#subtitle) {font-weight:bold}
```

Comment: if you change `h1` to bold, you need to change `span` to normal, because child elements are inherting css from parents

Comment: The child selector is `>` instead of `<`

Comment: Do you want just the text `This is the Title`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract just the title text, but not the subtitle, use the following:

```
var text = $("#banner").contents().filter(function () {
  if (this.nodeType == 3) { // Text Node
    return this;
  }        
})[0];
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3zL27/)**.

Answer (score 2):

See http://jsfiddle.net/PhSBE/

Just use

```
#banner{font-weight:bold} /* Title's rules */
#banner>#subtitle{font-weight:normal} /* Subtitle's rules */
```

**Edit:**

If you want to extract the text you could see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12135377/1529630

It's a function that extracts the text from an element, ignoring HTML elements.

Comment: ok thanks. What if I wanted to use the value of the h1 (without the span) as a variable in jQuery? maybe a new question..

Comment: @nathanbweb What do you mean with "value". CSS value? `el.nodeValue`?

Comment: sorry I meant the text within the h1 but outside the span

Answer (score 1):

if you change `h1` to bold, you need to change `span` to normal, because child elements are inherting css from parents

If you want to make some attributes to `This is the Title` only you need to make another `<span>` for it.